# xpath: exclude text that is part of an attribute value

Tags: php, xpath

I need to parse a chunk of html looking for a specific term, and wrap all instances of that term inside a A tag (with class "keyword").

To do that, i parse the html bit using xpath and it works well...

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//text()[contains(., "CLEA")]');
```

except in some rare cases, where the term is inside an attribute value, in which case some recursion occurs and the html breaks:

```
Hello <a class="tag" title="this is <a class="tag" href="#">CLEA</a>">CLEA</a>, hello!
```

When what i want is

```
Hello <a class="tag" title="this is CLEA">CLEA</a>, hello!
```

I'm struggling to correct my xpath query to exclude text that is part of an attribute value.

Your help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Here is a sample of the html that is being parsed using Xpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
Carte Blanche aux Artistes du <a class="tag" href="?tag=clea" rel="tag-definition" title="Click here to learn more about CLEA">CLEA</a>
14.01 - 19.01.2013
at: 
Gare Numérique de Jeumont, France
Organised by:
DRAC, Nord-Pas de Calais
Education National Nord-Pas de Calais
In the context of :
CLEA, résidence-mission
Contrat Local d'Education Artistique
http://cleavaldesambre.wordpress.com/
With: Martin Mey, Stephane Querrec, Woudi Tat, Marie Morel, LAb[au]
LAb[au] featured projects: <a title="Click here to learn more about f5x5x1" href="?tag=f5x5x1" rel="tag-definition" class="tag">Framework f5x5x1</a>, kinetic light art installation
<a title="Click here to learn more about binary waves" href="?tag=binary+waves" rel="tag-definition" class="tag">binary waves</a>, cybernetic light art installation</p>
```

***update 2***
The xpath is used in php like this

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf8');
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach ($tags as $t) {
        $label = $t['label'];
        $nodes = $xpath->query('//text()[contains(., "' . $label . '")]');
        $urlVersion = htmlentities(urlencode($label));

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $link = '<a class="tag" rel="tag-definition" title="Click to know more about ' . $label . '" href="?tag='.$urlVersion.'">'.$label.'</a>';
            $replaced = str_replace($label, $link, $node->textContent);
            $newNode = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
            $newNode->appendChild(new DOMText($replaced));
            $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
        }
    }

    $text= $dom->saveHTML();
```

The error occurs because one tag is "les amis de CLEA" and another tag is "CLEA".

Comment: thats invalid html. not even well formed. don't expect xpath to work with this

Comment: This is just for the sake of illustrating my question. The xpath query works fine with the provided html, unless in a few cases like stated.

Comment: I would really like to help you, but you must admit that this is non well formed html. your queries may working as domdocument is much forgiving when it comes to non well formed xml. but there is no way to select non well formed nodes with xpath. btw, can you show a little bit more of the document and queries which are working?

Comment: As per your request, i've added a raw copy of the html produced by the system and sent to xpath. thank you.

Comment: hmm, the html you've posted looks well-formed. seems, that problem that you are seeing happens only on some requests but not at all?

Comment: exact. Edge cases. apparently, it messes up with the "clea" instances inside the A attributes values.

Comment: I assume that you have no control over the remote pages?

Comment: content is furnished via an old CMS. End user is using a FCKEditor wysiwyg to create the content. I'm thinking there may be a clash in the way i process the parsing. I'll put some more php code in a second . There seems to be a clash between two keywords, one containing the other.

Comment: the general solution would be: fix old content to be well-formed. validate input and don't allow invalid html as input anymore

Comment: It is well-formed. It becomes badly formed during php processing inside the loop that i posted here. I fail to understand why: the produced anchor link gets parsed as text when the other tag's turn has come. I'll dig into DomText()...

Comment: By the sounds of it, the problem is that while processing one tag you're inserting a text node that contains markup that matches the next tag. The best solution would be to avoid including markup in a text node (it'll probably wind-up being quoted by your library anyway) and create the actual DOM for the `<a>` element you're trying to insert. That way your xpath (which only looks for text nodes) won't match it.

Comment: It make sense, but not sure yet how to do that. I'll have a try!

Comment: I looked again at my code, but i think your suggestion will break the str_replace(), which needs a string to work.

Answer (score 1):

That expression should not return attribute values. This looks like a bug in the PHP XPath implementation. In Xpath `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. Descendants do not include attributes. Even if they did, `text()` without an axis is short for `child::text()`, and attributes do not have child nodes. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes

So you need a workaround. The fully expanded expression you're using is `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::text()[contains(., "CLEA")]`. So let's try tweaking that. Instead of `node()`, try `*`, which only matches elements:

```
/descendant-or-self::*/text()[contains(., "CLEA")]
```

Or try using the `text()` node test directly on the `descendant-or-self` axis:

```
/descendant-or-self::text()[contains(., "CLEA")]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried them, but unfortunately, the same issue happens with both of your proposals. They're valid, though, as all the other cases still work.